# How to have fixed points in one screen using and then swipe to get to the next page using ios-charts?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I am using Swift trying to generate chart using the ios-charts api and having trouble containing same amount of point in the scene now. The chart is beautiful when having 5 points, like this [picture with 5 points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGEGv.png), however, when it comes to more points, it is really messy: [picture with more points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mNSX.png). So is there a way for me to keep just 5 points every scene and let the user swipe to get to another page? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could plot your chart into a scroll view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can limit visible X range like so..

```
lineChartView.setVisibleXRange(minXRange: 5, maxXRange: 5);
```

This will make only 5 points visible at a time, and will allow the user to scroll left or right for more.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above - you can set same values for min and max in:

```
func setVisibleXRange(minXRange minXRange: CGFloat, maxXRange: CGFloat)
```

If you want your chart to be able to zoom (probably you do), then you need to change these values again in delegate methods, setting different numbers, so you can zoom chart e.g.

```
func chartScaled(chartView: ChartViewBase, scaleX: CGFloat, scaleY: CGFloat) {
    self.chartView.setVisibleXRange(minXRange: 1, maxXRange: 10)
}
```